# How to add an object to a view after a successful login using spring security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, thymeleaf

After a successful login, I'm trying to redirect to a page that requires an object to be instantiated, as described here in my HomeController:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/","/home"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView home() {
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("home");
    view.addObject("client", new Client());
    return view;
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to do this using spring security, as the only setup I can do is to set the page after a successful login:

```
.formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
    .permitAll()
```

How can I add this object to the view after a sucessful login using spring security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a WebSecurity configuration like this. You just need to add a `successHandler`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private SimpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

    @Bean("authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user1").password("{noop}user1Pass").roles("USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("admin1").password("{noop}admin1Pass").roles("ADMIN");
        // @formatter:on
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/anonymous*").anonymous()
            .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.html")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            // ...        
    }
}
```

SimpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler Class

```
// Change onAuthenticationSuccess logic as per your requirement

@Component
public class SimpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {


        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(arg0, arg1, "/home");


        /*
        Collectionextends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        authorities.forEach(authority -> {
            if(authority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_USER")) {
                try {
                    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(arg0, arg1, "/user");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if(authority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                try {
                    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(arg0, arg1, "/admin");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
        });

        */


    }

}
```

This will redirect your call to `"/home"` and controller will further take care of loading your objects.

More detail [here](https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-boot-security-redirect-after-login)